# Adding to the java.library.path or jna.library.path on OSX

Tags: rococoa

I am trying to get Rococoa set up in order to attempt to incorporate a simple Cocoa widget into my java application, but the instruction tell me to add their bin directory to my jna.library.path variable but I do not know how to find this on OSX.  How would I do this?